# Retrieve rowid for a row in an sqlite result set

Tags: c, sqlite

Utilizing the sqlite c interface I need a way to find the rowid for a row in a result set.  The select statement that created the result set does not include the rowid column in the result set.

Assume that I have a successful SQLITE_ROW return from sqlite3_step(stmt).
How can I retrieve the rowid for the current row?

I have no control over the select statement that returned the results.  Please don't suggest SELECT rowid, ....

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Best case would be if the result set you get includes an integer primary key value, in which case that's the same as the rowid. Or if you've got a non-integer primary key you could use that to issue another SELECT query, but if neither of those are possible I think you're out-of-luck I'm afraid.